# Codeigniter insert double quotes

Tags: php, codeigniter, double-quotes

Hi I have a dropdown that needs to be saved in a MYSQL table, and this happens thru this code:

```
    $pjt_table = 'music_fisica';

    $full_pjt_save = array(
        'physical_format_vinile' => $this->input->post('formato_vinile'),
        );

    $pjt_save = array(
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'id_acquisto' => $this->input->post('id_acquisto'),
        'pjt_name' => $this->input->post('pjt_name'),
        'pjt_type_name' => $pjt_table,
        'pjt_table' => $pjt_table
        );

    //Full Project
    $added_fields = $full_pjt_save+array('last_mod' => time());
    $this->db->where('id_acquisto', $this->input->post('id_acquisto'));
    //$this->db->set('physical_format_vinile', $this->input->post('formato_vinile'), FALSE);
    $save_full_pjt_to_db = $this->db->update('progetti_'.$pjt_table, $added_fields);
    $pjt_table_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->where('id_acquisto', $this->input->post('id_acquisto'));
    $this->db->update('progetti', array('distrib_fisica' => '1'));

    $exist_pjt = $this->db->get_where('progetti_'.$pjt_table, array('id_acquisto' => $this->input->post('id_acquisto')));
```

The problem is that the dropdown contains a double quote and get cut off when saved to the table.

And this `45 Giri (7" Singolo, 45 Giri)` becomes  this `45 Giri (7`.

I tried changing the config adding the double quotes

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\"';`

but this doesn't change anything. I tried the XSS filtering false

`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;`

also this doesn't change a thing.
Any suggest?

Comment: The value is incorect only in the table ? In the begenning of the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace the double quote with `&quot;` the html equivalent.

Something like:

```
$yourVariable= str_replace('\"', '&quot;', $yourVariable);
```

not tested

Comment: you don't have to escape double quote between simple quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the mistake was in the HTML:

```
<option value="<?= $value ?>"><?= $value ?></option>
```

This actually broke the value double quotes due to the item.

Tks everybody.